# Set EXPAND_XOP_INCLUDE for WSS4JOutInterceptor in apache cxf 3.0.X

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, cxf-client, xop

i want to avoid the automatic generation of the xop included from apache cxf (version 3.0.4) when set MTOM ENABLE to true how can i do that? for example, i have a soap service . it support the mtom but not the xop include annotation , so it refused my request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<soap:Body>
<ns2:receiveSip xmlns:ns2="http://sip.receive.core.iris.eng.it" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
<ns2:sipReceive>
<tipoSip>?</tipoSip>
<tipoProtezione>?</tipoProtezione>
<improntaAlgoritmo>SHA-256</improntaAlgoritmo>
<improntaCodifica>HEX</improntaCodifica>   <impronta>9e830c2ac56eca00023b17e3c17ed1014e055f960c3ee4778a84aa02c6dafcb9</impronta>
</ns2:sipReceive>
<arg1>
<dh>
**<xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:92dc39d3-e3d5-4aa2-a9cb-7582483934a4-1@cxf.apache.org"/>**
</dh>
</arg1>
</ns2:receiveSip>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

how can i set my request to this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
<soap:Body> 
<ns2:receiveSip xmlns:ns2="http://sip.receive.core.iris.eng.it" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
<ns2:sipReceive>
<tipoSip>?</tipoSip>
<tipoProtezione>?</tipoProtezione>    
<improntaAlgoritmo>SHA-256</improntaAlgoritmo>
<improntaCodifica>HEX</improntaCodifica>   <impronta>9e830c2ac56eca00023b17e3c17ed1014e055f960c3ee4778a84aa02c6dafcb9</impronta>
</ns2:sipReceive>
<arg1>
<dh>**cid:92dc39d3-e3d5-4aa2-a9cb-7582483934a4**</dh>
</arg1>
</ns2:receiveSip>
</soap:Body>  
</soap:Envelope>
```

so in the end i just want replace the:

```
<xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:92dc39d3-e3d5-4aa2-a9cb-7582483934a4-1@cxf.apache.org"/>
```

with

```
cid:940325888173
```

how can obtain this result? in more recent version there is a parameter for this https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/common/ConfigurationConstants.html#EXPAND_XOP_INCLUDE , how can i replicate in the older version?

Here the java code i used:

```
   public static <T> T buildServerWsdl(String endpointWsdl,final String username,final String password,
        final Class<T> serviceClass,boolean ignoreSSLCertificate,boolean useAuthorizationBasic,Map<String,String> supplierheaders) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, MalformedURLException{

    //Controllo wsdlurl
    URL wsdlURL;
    java.io.File wsdlFile = new java.io.File(endpointWsdl);

    if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
        wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
    } else {
        wsdlURL = new URL(endpointWsdl);
    }
    System.out.println(wsdlURL);


    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();            
    factory.setServiceClass(serviceClass);          
    factory.setAddress(endpointWsdl);
    //Abilita il loggin in ingresco ed uscita dei messaggi soap!    
    factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor(4*1024));
    factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor(4*1024));    

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T server = (T) factory.create();            

    // The BindingProvider interface provides access to the protocol binding and
    // to the associated context objects for request and response message processing.
    BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)server;
    Binding binding = prov.getBinding(); 
    ((SOAPBinding)binding).setMTOMEnabled(true);
    //Add handlers to the binding jaxb 
    java.util.List<javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler> handlers = binding.getHandlerChain();
    handlers.add(new JaxWsLoggingHandler());
    binding.setHandlerChain(handlers);

    Map<String, Object> req_ctx = prov.getRequestContext();
    req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointWsdl);
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    if(username != null && password != null){   
        headers.put("Username", Arrays.asList(username));
        headers.put("Password", Arrays.asList(password));
        //headers.put("Content-Type", Arrays.asList("text/xml")); //necessario specificare se si usa schema-core invece di XmlSchema

        prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
        prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

        if(supplierheaders !=null &&  supplierheaders.size() > 0){
            prov.getRequestContext().putAll(supplierheaders);
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : supplierheaders.entrySet()){
                headers.put(entry.getKey(), Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }

        Authenticator myAuth = new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(myAuth);                       
    }

    if(useAuthorizationBasic){
        String authorization = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode((username+":"+password).getBytes());
        headers.put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic " + authorization));
        req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
        //MessageContext mctx = wsctx.getMessageContext();
        Map<String, List<String>> http_headers = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) req_ctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
        List list = (List) http_headers.get("Authorization");
        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Authentication failed! This WS needs BASIC Authentication!");
        }

        String userpass = (String) list.get(0);
        userpass = userpass.substring(5);
        byte[] buf = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(userpass.getBytes());
        String credentials = new String(buf);         
        String usernamex = null;
        String passwordx = null;
        int p = credentials.indexOf(":");
        if (p > -1) {
            usernamex = credentials.substring(0, p);
            passwordx = credentials.substring(p+1);
        }   
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("There was an error while decoding the Authentication!");
        }
        // This should be changed to a DB / Ldap authentication check 
        if (usernamex.equals(username) && passwordx.equals(password)) {              
            //System.out.println("============== Authentication Basic OK =============");
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Authentication failed! Wrong username / password!");
        }
    } 
    //Client cl = ClientProxy.getClient(server);
    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client cl = org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(server);
    //=============================================================================================
    // Set up WS-Security Encryption
    // Reference: https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/using.html
    Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();      
    //props.put(ConfigurationConstants.EXPAND_XOP_INCLUDE_FOR_SIGNATURE, false);
    //props.put(ConfigurationConstants.EXPAND_XOP_INCLUDE, false);       
    //inProps.put("expandXOPIncludeForSignature", false);
    //inProps.put("expandXOPInclude", false);
    //WSS4JOutInterceptor wss4jOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(inProps);

    //ClientProxy.getClient(client).getOutInterceptors().add(wss4jOut);
    //cl.getInInterceptors().add(wss4jOut);
    //cl.getOutInterceptors();
    //==============================================================================================

    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) cl.getConduit();

    //disable ssl certificate handshake
    if(ignoreSSLCertificate){
        String targetAddr = httpConduit.getTarget().getAddress().getValue();
        if (targetAddr.toLowerCase().startsWith("https:")) {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {            
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];}
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
            } };

            // Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
            //HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier(){public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }};

            TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
            tlsParams.setTrustManagers(trustAllCerts);
            tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
            httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);

            //SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            //sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

        }
    }

    AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy = httpConduit.getAuthorization();
    authorizationPolicy.setUserName(username);
    authorizationPolicy.setPassword(password);

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(10000);//10sec
    httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(60000);

    httpClientPolicy.setContentType("application/soap+xml"); 

    httpConduit.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
    return server;              
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem with the version 4.3.7 of jboss-cxf-client.

There appears to be several ways to disable CXF, none of them worked for the version we used of the lib. For documentation purpose here are the various methods that did not work for us:

```
// Method 1    
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("mtom-enabled", Boolean.FALSE);
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("write.attachments", Boolean.FALSE);
// Method 2    
SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) (((BindingProvider) bindingProvider).getBinding());
    binding.setMTOMEnabled(false);
```

This did not work for due to a bug in CXF which makes it impossible to disable automatic conversion. The work around was to set the threshold for automatic conversion to the maximum. To do this, add this as a feature to your port

```
new javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature(false, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

This fixed the issue for us.

Comment: Thank you we found this issue updating CXF from 3.3.2 to 3.3.4 - sounds like 3.3.2 had a 'regression' since we just migrate to CXF. you saved my day - here is the connected issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60023556/how-to-avoid-xop-generation-in-cxf-behaviour-changed-between-3-3-2-and-3-3-4