# How to avoid XOP generation in CXF - behaviour changed between 3.3.2 and 3.3.4

Tags: cxf, apache-tomee, xop

This issue involves recent CXF change (3.3.2->3.3.4).

We are sending a SOAP  request to our partner with image contents
On TomEE 8.0.0 (CXF 3.3.2), the SOAP request generated doesn't include XOP generation :

```
<ns3:Picture>
<ns6:Image>
<ns6:StorageFormat>JPG</ns6:StorageFormat>
<ns6:Length>13286</ns6:Length>
<ns6:Buffer>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAlgCWAAD//gAfTE (...) VBRCB=</ns6:Buffer>
</ns6:Image>
</ns3:Picture>
<ns3:Signature>
<ns6:Image>
<ns6:StorageFormat>TIF</ns6:StorageFormat>
<ns6:Length>700</ns6:Length>
<ns6:Buffer>SUkqAAgAAAATAP4ABAABAAAAAgAAAAABBAABAA (...) AA+==</ns6:Buffer>
</ns6:Image>
</ns3:Signature>
```

Running the code, isMTOMEnabled() return false

```
SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) ((BindingProvider) port).getBinding();
boolean mtomEnabled = binding.isMTOMEnabled();
```

Same war deployed on TomEE 8.0.1 (CXF 3.3.4). Now CXF generates (unrequested) XOP

```
<ns3:Picture>
<ns6:Image>
<ns6:StorageFormat>JPG</ns6:StorageFormat>
<ns6:Length>12099</ns6:Length>
<ns6:Buffer>
<xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:61bc1e4b-5e7c-47ea-ae1e-fc0ce1edbdd5-1@www.astra.admin.ch"/>
</ns6:Buffer>
</ns6:Image>
</ns3:Picture>
<ns3:Signature>
<ns6:Image>
<ns6:StorageFormat>TIF</ns6:StorageFormat>
<ns6:Length>580</ns6:Length>
<ns6:Buffer>
<xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:61bc1e4b-5e7c-47ea-ae1e-fc0ce1edbdd5-2@www.astra.admin.ch"/>
</ns6:Buffer>
</ns6:Image>
</ns3:Signature>
```

As our partner is not able to parse xop, how can avoid xop SOAP inclusion and get same result as previously with CXF 3.3.2?

Comment: Here is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038257/set-expand-xop-include-for-wss4joutinterceptor-in-apache-cxf-3-0-x

Comment: PersonPortType portType = ((PersonService) getService()).getPersonHttpSoap11Port(new javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature(false, Integer.MAX_VALUE));